# How can I add a bottom line on TextField (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, textfield, swiftui

I use `Rectangle()` to adding a bottom border on TextField (SwiftUI)

But I want to use `protocol TextFieldStyle` for a bottom line on TextField Style like an RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle

How can I make a custom style for TextField without using Rectangle?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/staticmember

[image]

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var username = "Text Hellow"
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            TextField($username)
                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 1.0, alignment: .bottom)
                .relativeWidth(1)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)

        }
        .padding()
    }

    func editChanged() {

    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution of kontiki does not work with **Beta 6**, though.
So I created a solution where I embed a TextField and a drawn bottom line in a new view. You can just copy the code and use it by writing `TextFieldWithBottomLine(placeholder: "My placeholder")` Used in a view it looks like:

[image: Usage of TextView with bottom line]

The first thing I create is a horizontal line:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HorizontalLineShape: Shape {

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {

        let fill = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height)
        var path = Path()
        path.addRoundedRect(in: fill, cornerSize: CGSize(width: 2, height: 2))

        return path
    }
}

struct HorizontalLine: View {
    private var color: Color? = nil
    private var height: CGFloat = 1.0

    init(color: Color, height: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
    }

    var body: some View {
        HorizontalLineShape().fill(self.color!).frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: height, maxHeight: height)
    }
}

struct HorizontalLine_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HorizontalLine(color: .black)
    }
}
```

Next I create a view that contains a TextField and the HorizontalLine below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextFieldWithBottomLine: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    private var placeholder = ""
    private let lineThickness = CGFloat(2.0)

    init(placeholder: String) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
         TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
            HorizontalLine(color: .black)
        }.padding(.bottom, lineThickness)
    }
}

struct TextFieldWithBottomLine_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextFieldWithBottomLine(placeholder: "My placeholder")
    }
}
```

To see it in action I created a sample view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SampleView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @ObservedObject var model: LoginModel

    init() {
        self.model = LoginModel()
    }

    init(model: LoginModel) {
        self.model = model
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextFieldWithBottomLine(placeholder: "My placeholder").padding(24)
    }

    func initialActions() {

    }

    func reactOnButtonClick() {

    }
}

struct SampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SampleView()
    }
}
```

Comment: If no animation is going to be supported, we can make `color` and `height` to be `private let`.

Answer (score 46):

**Divider**

A visual element that can be used to separate other content.

You can set `color` and `height`

```
Divider()
 .frame(height: 1)
 .padding(.horizontal, 30)
 .background(Color.red)
```

[image]

```
struct LoginField: View {

    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
                .padding(.horizontal, 30).padding(.top, 20)
            Divider()
                .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            TextField("Password", text: $password)
                .padding(.horizontal, 30).padding(.top, 20)
            Divider()
                .padding(.horizontal, 30)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note that you gain platform-suggested spacing by using `.padding(.horizontal)` (without specifying an explicit length)

Answer (score 32):

Using `.overlay`

```
TextField("mail@example.com", text: $email)
        .overlay(VStack{Divider().offset(x: 0, y: 15)})
```

[image]

the use of `VStack` is to ensure that the `Divider` is always horizontal.

Comment: Simply brilliant. Best answer.

Comment: why not use just `.overlay(Divider(), alignment: .bottom)`

Comment: What if I want to have different color divider?

Comment: @NeerajJoshi did you try with the foreground color modifier?

Comment: @iGhost Yes I tried, it is not working.

Comment: Baking in the y offset like this is not something you'd want to ship to production. It's going to cause issues once some of your users have larger accessibility text sizes enabled.

Answer (score 11):

To achieve a custom style for a TextField without using Rectangle and instead conforming to the TextFieldStyle protocol in SwiftUI

```
struct BottomLineTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        VStack() {
            configuration
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 0.5, alignment: .bottom)
                .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
TextField("Name", text: $presenter.name).textFieldStyle(BottomLineTextFieldStyle())
```

Answer (score 9):

To define a custom style, you can use the code below. The Rectangle is used eventually, but inside the custom style, not in your view code. Is this what you want?

**Note: Tested on Beta 3**

To use your custom initialiser:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var username = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            TextField("Enter text", text: $username)
                .textFieldStyle(.myOwnStyle)

        }.frame(width:300)
    }
}
```

Your custom initialiser implementation:

```swift
public struct MyOwnTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    public func _body(configuration: TextField<Self.Label>) -> some View {

        VStack() {
            configuration
                .border(Color.blue, width: 2)
                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 1.0, alignment: .bottom)
                .relativeWidth(1)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)

        }
    }
}

extension StaticMember where Base : TextFieldStyle {
    public static var myOwnStyle: MyOwnTextFieldStyle.Member {
        StaticMember<MyOwnTextFieldStyle>(MyOwnTextFieldStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, That's what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: No more StaticMember in beta 6 any more. Any replacement?

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to add a divider under the textfield:

```
private let textFieldLength:CGFloat = 200
var body: some View {
     VStack {
         TextField("placeHolder", text: .constant("")).frame(width: textFieldLength, height: 30, alignment: .center)
         Divider().frame(width: textFieldLength, height: 2, alignment: .center)
     }
}
```

or use overlay

```
 TextField("", text: .constant(""))
  .frame(width: textFieldLength, height: 30, alignment: .center)
  .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
  .overlay(Divider().frame(width: textFieldLength, height: 2, alignment: .center), alignment: .bottom)
```

Comment: I think that overlay's solutions are more cleaner than others

Comment: I love the simplicity of the first snippet. Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Try it another way

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // change frame as per requirement
           TextField("Please enter text", text: $name)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 30, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            LineView().frame(width: 300, height: 1.0, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

**LineView** : Create custom wrappers for a `UIView`

```
struct LineView: UIViewRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewType = UIView
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LineView>) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LineView>) {
    }
}
```

Comment: creating a UIViewRepresentable for something that can be created with Divider/Overlay/Rectangle wastes time and code.